# Is there a hosted Stack Overflow-like (clone) framework?

Tags: discussion, clone, forums

I am aware of the [list of valid SO clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones), but was wondering if anyone was aware of a hosted solution for private use?

Stack Exchange is an example, but SE is not for private use. As far as I'm aware, all of the Stack Exchange sites are public.

**EDIT**

Since this was posted, the above list of valid SO clones, has been updated to include hosted solutions.

[Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

Comment: I don't know about any others

Comment: One of the big clones offered commercial hosting, but I forgot which one.